# Handle Optimistic Concurrency in SQL Server with EF Core - when updating child, how to update the parent?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, concurrency, ef-core-3.1

I have two entities one of them `paper` and the other one is `paper line`.

I am using SQL Server to store the entity records, each entity is represented by a table in the database

`PaperEntity` contains columns

```
Id, Color, TimeStamp (RowVersion), etc...
```

`PaperLineEntity` contains columns

```
Id, PaperId(FK), lineContent, TimeStamp (RowVersion), etc...
```

I am thinking about how can I prevent two users to update two different lines in the same paper, my idea is when you update the line you have to update the timestamp for the paper record that this line belongs to it, any ideas on how can I manage that in EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

When fetch lines of Paper, get TimeStamp(RowVersion) too,
When user save the line,
first compare timestamp
if it is different, so you return an error else it is same, then you Allow update it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concurrency tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency). Idea is the same as you described: you have a special property which is updated together with each update of entity. You should mark this property using special attribute or using fluent configuration. EF Core will compare `old_value` (initially read from db) and `current_value` (currently presented in database) automatically during each update. If they are not equal special exception will be thrown.